# VBA in Excel Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to VBA and I'm using it to colour code a graph based on certain values. Sometimes when I step through the code it works, but when I try and run it end-to-end I get an error. Any help will be appreciated.

The program stops at "For i = 1 To ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count
                      With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i)" with the error!!!

```
Sub UpdChartColours()
    Dim i As Long

    Dim num1 As Integer
    Dim num2 As Integer
    Dim num3 As Integer
    Dim num4 As Integer
    Dim num5 As Integer
    Dim num6 As Integer


    num1 = Sheet1.Cells.Item(19, "E").Value
    num2 = Sheet1.Cells.Item(21, "E").Value
    num3 = Sheet1.Cells.Item(23, "E").Value
    num4 = Sheet1.Cells.Item(25, "E").Value
    num5 = Sheet1.Cells.Item(27, "E").Value
    num6 = Sheet1.Cells.Item(29, "E").Value



     For i = 1 To ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count
        With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i)


            If i = 1 And num1 = 1 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            ElseIf i = 1 And num1 = 2 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 30, 0)
            ElseIf i = 1 And num1 = 3 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 95, 0)
            ElseIf i = 1 And num1 = 4 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 145, 0)
            ElseIf i = 1 And num1 = 5 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 190, 0)
            ElseIf i = 1 And num1 = 6 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 215, 0)
            ElseIf i = 1 And num1 = 7 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 230, 0)
            ElseIf i = 1 And num1 = 8 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 1 And num1 = 9 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(200, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 1 And num1 = 10 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(170, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 1 And num1 = 11 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(140, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 1 And num1 = 12 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(110, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 1 And num1 = 13 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(80, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 1 And num1 = 14 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(20, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 1 And num1 = 15 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 1 And num1 = 16 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 30)

            End If

            If i = 3 And num2 = 1 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            ElseIf i = 3 And num2 = 2 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 30, 0)
            ElseIf i = 3 And num2 = 3 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 95, 0)
            ElseIf i = 3 And num2 = 4 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 145, 0)
            ElseIf i = 3 And num2 = 5 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 190, 0)
            ElseIf i = 3 And num2 = 6 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 215, 0)
            ElseIf i = 3 And num2 = 7 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 230, 0)
            ElseIf i = 3 And num2 = 8 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 3 And num2 = 9 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(200, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 3 And num2 = 10 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(170, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 3 And num2 = 11 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(140, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 3 And num2 = 12 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(110, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 3 And num2 = 13 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(80, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 3 And num2 = 14 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(20, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 3 And num2 = 15 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 3 And num2 = 16 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 30)

            End If

            If i = 5 And num3 = 1 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            ElseIf i = 5 And num3 = 2 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 30, 0)
            ElseIf i = 5 And num3 = 3 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 95, 0)
            ElseIf i = 5 And num3 = 4 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 145, 0)
            ElseIf i = 5 And num3 = 5 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 190, 0)
            ElseIf i = 5 And num3 = 6 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 215, 0)
            ElseIf i = 5 And num3 = 7 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 230, 0)
            ElseIf i = 5 And num3 = 8 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 5 And num3 = 9 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(200, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 5 And num3 = 10 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(170, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 5 And num3 = 11 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(140, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 5 And num3 = 12 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(110, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 5 And num3 = 13 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(80, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 5 And num3 = 14 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(20, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 5 And num3 = 15 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 5 And num3 = 16 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 30)

            End If

            If i = 7 And num4 = 1 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            ElseIf i = 7 And num4 = 2 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 30, 0)
            ElseIf i = 7 And num4 = 3 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 95, 0)
            ElseIf i = 7 And num4 = 4 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 145, 0)
            ElseIf i = 7 And num4 = 5 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 190, 0)
            ElseIf i = 7 And num4 = 6 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 215, 0)
            ElseIf i = 7 And num4 = 7 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 230, 0)
            ElseIf i = 7 And num4 = 8 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 7 And num4 = 9 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(200, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 7 And num4 = 10 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(170, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 7 And num4 = 11 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(140, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 7 And num4 = 12 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(110, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 7 And num4 = 13 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(80, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 7 And num4 = 14 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(20, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 7 And num4 = 15 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 7 And num4 = 16 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 30)

            End If

            If i = 9 And num5 = 1 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            ElseIf i = 9 And num5 = 2 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 30, 0)
            ElseIf i = 9 And num5 = 3 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 95, 0)
            ElseIf i = 9 And num5 = 4 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 145, 0)
            ElseIf i = 9 And num5 = 5 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 190, 0)
            ElseIf i = 9 And num5 = 6 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 215, 0)
            ElseIf i = 9 And num5 = 7 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 230, 0)
            ElseIf i = 9 And num5 = 8 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 9 And num5 = 9 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(200, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 9 And num5 = 10 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(170, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 9 And num5 = 11 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(140, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 9 And num5 = 12 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(110, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 9 And num5 = 13 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(80, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 9 And num5 = 14 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(20, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 9 And num5 = 15 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 9 And num5 = 16 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 30)

            End If


            If i = 11 And num6 = 1 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            ElseIf i = 11 And num6 = 2 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 30, 0)
            ElseIf i = 11 And num6 = 3 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 95, 0)
            ElseIf i = 11 And num6 = 4 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 145, 0)
            ElseIf i = 11 And num6 = 5 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 190, 0)
            ElseIf i = 11 And num6 = 6 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 215, 0)
            ElseIf i = 11 And num6 = 7 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 230, 0)
            ElseIf i = 11 And num6 = 8 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 11 And num6 = 9 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(200, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 11 And num6 = 10 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(170, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 11 And num6 = 11 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(140, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 11 And num6 = 12 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(110, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 11 And num6 = 13 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(80, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 11 And num6 = 14 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(20, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 11 And num6 = 15 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            ElseIf i = 11 And num6 = 16 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 30)

            End If


        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveChart` Most probably because there is no activechart at that moment. Avoid using that. Use a Chart object and then do what you are trying to do.

Comment: is the activesheet in sheet1 ? because i think you need to

Comment: @SiddharthRout is right. Chart Object definition is good or you can activate the chart before running this sub.

Answer (score 0):

sorry form my english, you need to nest the if and eventually use a select case like this:

```
    Select Case i
    Case Is = 1
        Select Case Num1
            Case Is = 1
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            Case Is = 2
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 95, 0)
            Case Is = 3
            '... insert all your cases for Num1

        End Select
    Case Is = 3
        Select Case Num1
            Case Is = 1
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            Case Is = 2
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 30, 0)
            Case Is = 3
            '... insert all your cases for Num1
        End Select
    Case Is = 3
    '... insert all your cases for i and so on
End Select
```

otherwise for further synthesis you'll need an algorithm for generating the colour codes starting from your input data (but i think it would be too much complex)

Comment: Posted Question is about Run-time error. Though using case or other way to make it short or neat is good, it will not resolve error issue.